# Update Disqus comments counter in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blogger, disqus

I am working on a Google Blog and Disqus comments counter updates with delay up to 10 minutes. So I try to make it counts in real time. I contacted with Disqus support and they told me this...

> Please note that the comment count script is not expected to update in
>   Realtime, and can experience delays of up to 10 minutes when
>   configured properly.
>
> If you are looking for realtime comment counts, we do have some
>   Advanced Options which you are free to implement on your site, though
>   any additional questions regarding these methods should be directed
>   towards our Developer Forum:
>   - Use a hook to increment the displayed comment count every time a new comment comes in in real-time which would be possible to do since
>   Disqus is already loaded in the background. To accomplish this, you
>   could just provide a callback as described on this
>   page:https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-capturing-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks
>   and increment the count every time your callback gets called.
>
> If you still would like to poll, try using the comment count script as
>   described on this page:
>   https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-tightening-your-disqus-integration.
>   Once this is loaded, you can just call the function:
>   DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({reload: true}); when you want to poll and it
>   will update the comment count for you. This endpoint is heavily
>   optimized on our end for this use case.

My problem is... Where exactly should I place this `DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({reload: true});`? Cause I have make some tries but, nothing!!!

Here is an example of my code...

**Disqus comments count link:**

```
<b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'>
    <a class='disqus-comment-count' expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#disqus_thread&quot;' onclick='return false;'>Counting...</a>
</b:if>
```

**Disqus comments widget:**

```
<b:widget id='HTML6' locked='false' title='Disqus Comments' type='HTML' visible='true'>
  <b:includable id='main'>
    <div id='comments' name='comments'>
      <div id="disqus_thread" />
    </div>
  </b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

**Disqus count.js:**

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//my-shortname.disqus.com/count.js" async='async'></script>
```

**Load Disqus comments on click:**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comments').on('click', function() {
      var disqus_shortname = 'my-shortname';
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
        dataType: "script",
        cache: true
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your blog -

```
<script>
  var disqus_config = function () {
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function() { DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({reset: true}); }];
  };
</script>
```

This will update the comment count every time a new comment is added via the page.